# Python 2.7 : how to execute a method from one class in another class ("__init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)" error)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to implement a Tetris game in python from a template provided by my teacher. I have a "Tetris" class :

```
class Tetris():
''' Tetris class: Controls the game play
    Attributes:
        SHAPES - type: list (list of Shape classes)
        DIRECTION - type: dictionary - converts string direction to
            (dx, dy)
        BOARD_WIDTH - type:int - the width of the board
        BOARD_HEIGHT - type:int - the height of the board
        board - type:Board - the tetris board
        window - type:Window - the window for the tetris game
        delay - type:int - the speed in milliseconds for moving the shapes
        current_shapes - type: Shape - the current moving shape on the 
            board
'''
SHAPES = [I_shape, J_shape, L_shape, O_shape, S_shape, T_shape, Z_shape]
DIRECTION = {'Left':(-1, 0), 'Right':(1, 0), 'Down':(0, 1)}
BOARD_WIDTH = 10
BOARD_HEIGHT = 20

def __init__(self, window):
    self.board = Board(window, self.BOARD_WIDTH, self.BOARD_HEIGHT)
    self.window = window
    self.delay = 1000 #ms

    # sets up the keyboard events
    # when a key is called the method key_pressed will be called
    self.window.bind_all('<Key>', self.key_pressed)

    # set the current shape to a random new shape
    self.current_shape = self.create_new_shape()

    # Draw the current_shape on the board

    # To automatically move the pieces, animate the shape!
    ####  YOUR CODE HERE ####


def create_new_shape(self):
    ''' Return value: type: Shape

        Create a random new shape that is centered at the top of the board
            and returns the shape
    '''
    center = Point(0, 0)
    index = random.randrange(0, 6)
    return Tetris.SHAPES[index](center)

#other methods
```

and a "Board" class :

```
class Board():
''' Board class: Represents the Tetris board

    Attributes: width - type:int - width of the board in squares
                height - type:int - height of the board in squares
                canvas - type:CanvasFrame - where the pieces will be drawn
                grid - type:Dictionary - keeps track of the current state
                    of the board; stores the blocks for a given position
'''

def __init__(self, window, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height

    # create a canvas to draw the tetris shapes on
    self.canvas = CanvasFrame(window, self.width * Block.BLOCK_SIZE,
                                    self.height * Block.BLOCK_SIZE)
    self.canvas.setBackground('light gray')

    # create an empty dictionary
    # currently we have no shapes on the board
    self.grid = {}

def draw_shape(self, shape):
    ''' Parameters: shape - type: Shape
        Return value: type: bool

        Draws the shape on the board if there is space for it
            and returns True, otherwise it returns False
    '''
    if shape.can_move(self, 0, 0):
        shape.draw(self.canvas)
        return True
    return False
```

Now, I have to modify the "**init**" of Tetris so that it draws the current_shape on the board. When I try this :

```
Board().draw_shape(self.current_shape)
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tetris.py", line 475, in <module>
game = Tetris(window)
File "tetris.py", line 401, in __init__
Board().draw_shape(current_shape)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: `self.board.draw_shape(current_shape)` ?

Comment: The Board class need to pass 3 Arguments: window, width, height. If you want to draw the shape, you need to create before a instance of the board correctly

Comment: Yes ! self.board worked ! Thank you very much :)